# Flyway-Add a column to all tables containing a specified sufifix in the name

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, migration, flyway

Is it possible to add a column to all the tables that which name ends in a specific substring using Flyway? To give a better context of the problem I am trying to solve I will leave an example below:

In my database I have this two tables `saft_2020_1_111_nc_generalledgerentriestotals` and `saft_2017_2_112_nc_generalledgerentriestotals` and their names both end in `generalledgerentriestotals`.

Is there any way I can make my migration add the column to both the tables?
Making a migration for each table is not an option because there could be N tables that meet this requirement, so doing it manually for each one would be higly unproductive.

I am using MySQL has database but optimally the migration proccess should be agnostic if possible

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get all the table names with

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_name like '%generalledgerentriestotals';
```

Then in your flyway you can loop over this resultset and add the column with ALTER TABLE;

I'm not sure how you would make this agnostic, since the query to get tables is going to be different per provider.

Comment: so my migration should be done using a java class?

Comment: for agnostic I could use liquibase but it's not possible to alter all the tables with that suffix automatically

Comment: @Fabio I'd recommend using SQL based migrations for this, not Java based migrations. https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations

Comment: I've been using SQL migrations. But how can I loop Over the result set?